# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  9pm UTC / 5pm EDT on the 27th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Wednesday the 27th at 9pm UTC / 5pm EDT.**

[**view in other timezones**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=4&day=27&year=2011&hour=21&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 25th-28th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gis.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event **[here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/439/gis-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: +1 Nice idea.  Thanks for setting this up.

Comment: @Rebecca In order to "be on the lookout for email" one has to know what the originating address will be.  Could you share that with us?  At least the domain name?

Comment: @whuber, our emails come from stackoverflow.com or stackexchange.com.  My id is rebecca@.  I've only received 3 responses so far.  I'll just have to pick a time and hope if I don't hear from more people by tomorrow morning.

Comment: Rebecca, perhaps you could email the candidates to let them know? I just happened to check back on this thread, thanks for organizing this.

Comment: I think the regisister link might not be working properly. You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/439/gis-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)

Comment: @scw, shoot, I did forget to do that. ):  Correcting that now.

Comment: Im in Melbourne, so this is 7am for me.  Ill do my best to be on time.

Answer (score 3):

I will be creating a "digest" version of the GIS 2011 Town Hall Chat. This will be posted as one large Meta question. The digest will contain all the questions asked in the town hall and the candidates' answers, with none of the other conversation from the room.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests)

**Update: I am still working on the digest... the town hall got a bit... convoluted... in places, so sorting out what goes where is taking me longer than usual. Thanks for your patience!**.

[Here is the Town Hall Chat Digest](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/409/2758). If you see things which need to be corrected, missing answers, etc, please just let me know!